# how to extract values from an object nested inside array inside object and store it in different arrays JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
[{
    "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fa",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fb",
            "id": "5fd35931ec23f76d387d8464",
            "name": "dean"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fc",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "john"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fd",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "brad"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64558",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64559",
            "id": "5fd35931ec23f76d387d8464",
            "name": "dean"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e6455a",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "brad"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 0
}]
```

Quick overview: each object contains a different conversation data.
I want to extract the names out of each conversation and store them in a separate array.
for instance: `[[dean, john, brad], [dean, brad]]`

Comment: show what you have tried please so we can help you fix it

Comment: You have names with different ID's are they different names/people?  Can a person appear more than once in a list/conversation?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = [{
    "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fa",
    "contacts": [{
        "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fb",
        "id": "5fd35931ec23f76d387d8464",
        "name": "dean"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fc",
        "id": "12",
        "name": "john"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fd",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "brad"
      }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64558",
    "contacts": [{
        "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64559",
        "id": "5fd35931ec23f76d387d8464",
        "name": "dean"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e6455a",
        "id": "12",
        "name": "brad"
      }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 0
  }
];

const people = arr.map(ele => ele.contacts.map(contact => contact.name));
console.log(people);
```

Map the array:

```js
const people = arr.map(ele => ele.contacts.map(contact => contact.name));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can `map` over the elements and extract the data out.

```js
var your_elements_array = [{
    "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fa",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fb",
            "id": "5fd35931ec23f76d387d8464",
            "name": "dean"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fc",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "john"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fd",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "brad"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64558",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64559",
            "id": "5fd35931ec23f76d387d8464",
            "name": "dean"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e6455a",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "brad"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 0
}];
let x = your_elements_array.map(element => {
  return element["contacts"].map(element => {
    return element["name"];
  });
});
console.log(x);
```

```js
your_elements_array.map(element => {
  return element["contacts"].map(element => {
    return element["name"];
  });
});
```

Comment: what is `/* CODE */ ` since this is what the question is about, please provide that

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I left that space empty because I wanted Dean_Geva to store those names in an array and then later append that array into the array Dean_Geva wanted at the last.